# Circular clipping of a CSS3D object in Three.js

Tags: css, three.js

I'm using the wonderful Three.js CSS3D renderer to obtain great performance on phones and tablet as well as desktops.

I have added an overview Google map as a CSS3D object that rotates with the heading of the camera, and that works quite fine

```
//// add the mini map to CSS3D scene
    var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
    element.style.width = '300px';
    element.style.height = '300px';
    element.setAttribute("id", "miniMap");
    document.getElementById('containerMiniMap').appendChild( element );         
    var gMapObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
```

, but I would like **the map to have a circular clipping** to fit the design that requires the map being circular. I have a nice pic showing it but being new to stackoverflow I can't post pictures yet, so I hope my description will be precise enough to let you figure out ;)

After investigating, I found CSS methods to do this with either PNG masks or SVG path as show in [Clipping in CSS 2.1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/?redirect_from_locale=fr) but it seems overkill and still creates the problem of a square container even if the amp can be clipped.
Additionnally, a quick test shows that it works with an image but I couldn't make it work with an interactive google map, see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3FCcc/

What I would like to do is **to project the map CSS3D object (like a kind of texture) on a circle object** that would act like a mask on my google map.

```
 circle = createMesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(...
```

Anyone ever done this or any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Based on that article... I guess it should be something along the lines of this?

```
var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
element.style.width = '300px';
element.style.height = '300px';
element.style.clipPath = 'polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px, ...)';
```

Comment: Thanks MrDoob, I guess if you advise the CSS way that there is no easy way with the Three.js API. I'll give a try and post the result.

Comment: OK I tried with no luck, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3FCcc/ where you can see a circular clipping successfully applied to an image, but the google map seem to ignore the circular path, even if the circular clipping is applied to both the google map clip and the parent container clip. I re-opened the case ;)